# Persisting Hover State for Dynamically Generated Content

Tags: javascript, css, hover

I attempted to previously ask this question, but think I wasn't clear on the issue. I have a set of lis and content associated with the lis being generated dynamically like so:

```
var catCounter = sideCol.getElementsByTagName('li').length-1;
for(var i=0; i<catCounter; i++) {
    (function(ix){
        sideCol.getElementsByTagName('li')[ix].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
            // this.style.backgroundColor = '#828387';
            catContent[0].children[2].innerHTML = subMenuArr[ix];
        });
    })(i);
}
```

sideCol and catContent represent 2 separate sections of the menu and are in no way connected to each other. Every time a li from sideCol is hovered, catContent's inner HTML content is being dynamically changed. The problem is that hovering over the catContent loses the hover state of the sideCol li associated with that particular catContent. An additional issue is that the hover state of each li triggers an ::after state which I read JavaScript cannot control unless I'm mistaken. How can the li hover state persist when hovering into the catContent area? The hover state is trigger fine just hovering over the lis themselves.

Comment: Try and create a jsfiddle/codepen that demonstrates the issue as it would be much easier to help is we can see the code

Comment: Try mouseenter instead of mouseover so that the innerHTML of catContent stays the same until another li is hovered.

Comment: Use mouseenter instead of mouseover. If you need to change state use mouseleave.